# Redrawing a panel with information retrieved from a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to create a panel that will display different category selections. [image]

I need a label and an image to display. The label and the picture box will be set by the information I pulled from the database. I need them to be generated and fill in the circles (in a more linear fashion of course). So I can allow for data updating through the database, I need the number of picture boxes and labels to be dynamic. How would I, if its even possible, go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to give you some directions.
I would use a tableLayoutPanel. It is a powerful control, and if you study it you can achieve the result that you want.
With tableLayoutPanel You can have rows, and columns (with different size). Also you can add more rows/columns at runtime.
So let's say that your database return you 10 categories.
Then I would make 3 columns and 8 rows

```
 Rows/Columns      1                 2                     3   
       1        Label1            Label2                  Label3
       2     PictureBox1       PictureBox2             PictureBox3
       3        Label4            Label5                  Label6
       4     PictureBox4       PictureBox5             PictureBox6
       5        Label7            Label8                 Label9
       6     PictureBox7       PictureBox8             PictureBox9
       7        Label10          
       8     PictureBox10
```

You can choose to change the size of the form or keep the same size and have a scrollbar (in the case that you have to many categories)
I hope that I helped a little. Please let me know how you are going with this

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll begin reading up on table layout panels asap.